# What should I put in my conda envirnment file to install python-dev?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I have conda environment file `conda.yml`:

```
name: env

channels:
  - pytorch

dependencies:
  - python=3.7.*
  - python-dev
  - python3-distutils
```

But the line `- python-dev` and `python3-distutils` does not work. What should I put to get the python development tools?

Comment: Not totally sure, but I don't think you need it. Conda `python` builds already include the headers, so a separate `python-dev` package doesn't appear necessary. That is, observe that installing `python=3.7` in an env  populates `envs/my_env/include/python3.7m/` with `Python.h`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that is possible. I don't really know how to check to be sure. I just know I need them in my environment, and that somehow I am missing dependencies so I thought that was the problem, but you might be right.

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to include in your question what is failing to work/your end goal. Are you trying to manually compile something that links to libraries in the env, or are you using `conda-build`? The latter is supposed to [handle lib paths and includes automatically](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html#anaconda-compilers-and-conda-build-3) AFAIK, but I've only ever built non-compiled packages with it.

Comment: @merv thank you. Ya, what is actually failing is `conda env create -f conda.yml` when it reaches the `pip: - audioread` line. It fails with`anaconda3/envs/laugh/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1079, in _read
        raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
    configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
` `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`. But that is a totally new question which I should create.

Comment: I thought that it failed because I didn't have the python dev tools. But indeed maybe that is not the reason.

Comment: This would be a totally new question though. And I don't know how to ask it cleanly.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the PyPI version of `audioread`? I see it's slightly ahead of [Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/audioread) (2.1.8 vs 2.1.6), but [the release notes](https://pypi.org/project/audioread/#version-history) look like minor improvements - no major API additions or correctness bug fixes.

Comment: FYI: I updated the Conda Forge feedstock to have audioread v2.1.8, so you can now install the latest version without having to use `pip` (just need `- conda-forge` in your `channels:` section of the YAML).

Comment: Thank you @merv! I'm not sure how to use conda-forge, I never used that before (I think), where and how do I specify that I want `audioread` using conda-forge?

Comment: I tried `channels: -conda-forge` then `dependencies: -audioread` ... oh wow! it worked! Thank you so much!